# SharePoint 2016 - Word 2016 Add-in Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, word

Some users are receiving the following add-in error.

[image]

If they close out the error the files work just fine. I've searched all over including the add-ins enabled on our Word client and have found nothing...has anyone found a resolution to this error?

Comment: Is there a pattern detectable? Special user roles, special characters in document names, different patch states, etc.?
What shall this Add-In do and is it really neccessary for those users (or maybe all)?

Comment: No pattern. I have a similar case (both in SP2013 and SP2010) - few users on random documents. Sometimes one user on one document does get an error but after some time the same user can save the same document.. and two users on one document - one can save, second cannot. Feels super-random.

I have found some ways how to deal with this problem, by configuration Office, but nothing from the SharePoint side.

Comment: Is this an on premise SharePoint and an Office 365 Word license?

Comment: Yes - on-premise SharePoint and Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this may just be a client-side issue. We often have issues with Office and have to either have to repair Office, re-connect the Plugin, or in more dire situations, recreate their user profile on their machine.

If this Plugin requires either a Service, Feature, or Solution on the SharePoint side, you may want to try to uninstall/retract/etc then redeploy. Patching also can help this type of issue, but not normally.

If you give some more information on how the Plugin is installed/deployed to the users, what it's requirements are (Server side and Client side), we may be able to give better advise.

Comment: As I understand, this "feature" is OOB, came up with one of MS updates  [KB4011671] and nothing is specifically configured in Office, neither in SharePoint - so there is nothing to to re-deploy.

Comment: Then that tells me it’s an issue with Office installs and they may need to be repaired... as calls come in maybe try and remote in and do a quick Office repair and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Agree, that could be possible and might fix the problem. Although, my main point was - is there anything that could be done in SharePoint side?

Comment: I don’t think so, short of doing a patch with the most recent KB or reverting back to a KB you know works. I can’t say if that’ll fix anything though.

Answer (score 0):

I was Having this same issue. The issue is the current build of your SharePoint farm.

You need to upgrade to a more recent CU.

Answer (score -2):

I would set the log level of the trace log to verbose and reproduce the error while running ULS Viewer.

Somewhere you'll find SharePoint telling Word that this mysterious feature is not supported. And with this message from the ULS log, the community will surely be able to help you better :)

I documented the process of searching the ULS log a while ago on my blog: https://engineerer.ch/2019/01/04/how-to-find-errors-in-the-sharepoint-uls-log/

Comment: Why the downvotes? Thx for the feedback!